# Are <Ul>s allowed inside H1?

Tags: html, css, seo

I was wondering if there would be any problems if I added a list inside a H1 heading:

```
<h1>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="...">some link</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">another link</a></li>
  <li>current page</li>
 </ul>
</h1>
```

the list is a "breadcrumb" type navigation.

Or is it better to insert it inside the list?

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="...">some link</a></li>
 <li><a href="...">another link</a></li>
 <li><h1>current page</h1></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to represent here, semantically? If your page doesn't have a heading, I wouldn't give it a heading. If it does, I would, separate from breadcrumb navigation.

Comment: It doesn't, but one of list items could be the heading. I read somewhere that every page needs a H1, otherwise is bad for SEO. Is that true?

Comment: I wouldn't say bad for SEO. But the page "quality" certainly improves when you're using a H1 to identity the most important subject on the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not valid to have a ul inside a h1, the best way of checking is to use http://validator.w3.org/ to check your structure, that way the doctype you are using will be considered. (but it's still not valid!)

Comment: +1 Answer is correct: This is not valid. Second method would be better.

Answer (score 16):

Header elements like `<h1>` follow the *[phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#phrasing-content-0)* content model: if you wanted to follow the HTML specification to the letter, phrasing content can only contain regular text or other phrasing content. As `<ul>` elements aren't phrasing content, they're technically not allowed in `<h1>` elements.

Your second example—placing the `<h1>` elements within `<li>` elements—is valid markup and would be the preferred method of combining `<h1>` and `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)** to check out whether or not it is valid :)

Comment: @Alexandra: That would be a different question I suppose so that you can get more targeted answers :)

Comment: It would affect search engine pisition as the header could end up being unrelated to the content.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question, no, that doesn't look like a sane thing to do with your markup, and even if it were technically valid (which I don't believe it is) I wouldn't advise doing it.

As for SEO, `h1` is used to some degree in search, though I believe it's not as important as the `<title>` element. However, if your page doesn't *have* a heading, semantically-speaking, I certainly wouldn't crowbar one in just to try and improve rankings. Put that "current page" text in the `<title>`, if appropriate, make the breadcrumb list a normal breadcrumb list, and don't bother with the h1 if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

this would display - however I think it would be considered bad practice as a list is not a header.
You'd be better off adding css styling so you could format you list to the desired size, font etc.